# parse a cv file

Tags: haskell

My code doesn't compile. It seems that the problem lies in the main function with lookup.
I am trying to parse an file that look like this :

auiauiaui@tsrntsr.epep 584756 "srtrtte"
jepeto@pinokio.disney 464456454 "cendrillon"

If you name the file lol and the code prog then calling prog lol 1 2 will return 464456454.

EDIT :

Thanks,

See I have a file named filetest like this :
field1-1 field1-2 field1-3
field2-1 field2-2 field2-3
field3-1 field3-2 field3-3
field4-1 field4-2 field4-3
field5-1 field5-2 field5-3

Now my piece of code is suppose to grab a field given the line and the rank.
mycode filetest give me the number of lines in the file (so that i can use a script for each lines).

Here some example :
mycode filetest 1 2 -> field1-2
mycode filetest 2 2 -> field2-2
mycode filetest 3 4 -> field3-4
mycode filetest 3 2 -> field3-2
mycode filetest 2 5 -> field2-5
mycode filetest 1 4 -> field1-4

Now each field contain a String.

What i do is grab the file as a string then grab the line wanted (with lines) and then grab the field (with words).

I corrected my errors (thanks to the #haskell and #haskell-fr channel and you). But my code doesn't work as expected at all.

Any help shall be appreciated. Here is the néw code :

```
import System.Environment
import System.IO

fieldArg :: Int -> [String] -> String
fieldArg x a = if length a > 2
                then if x < 4 then a !! x else "field number is too high"
                else "field number is too low"

lineArg :: Int -> [String] -> String
lineArg x a
    | x > length a = "line number is too big"
    | x < 1        = "line number is too low"
    | otherwise    = a !! x

extrcta :: Int -> Int -> String -> String
extrcta x n = fieldArg x . words . lineArg n . lines


argList :: String -> [((Int, String), String -> String)]
argList n = let n1 = read n
            in [((1, n), extrcta 1 n1)
               ,((2, n), extrcta 2 n1)
               ,((3, n), extrcta 3 n1)
               ]


main :: IO ()
main = do
        args <- getArgs
        case args of
                   (path: opt1: opt2: _) -> case (read opt1, opt2) `lookup` argList opt2 of
                                                                                       Nothing -> putStrLn $ "Wrong argument " ++ opt1 ++ " or " ++ opt2
                                                                                       Just act -> withFile path ReadMode (\handle -> do
                                                                                                                                       contents <- hGetContents handle
                                                                                                                                       putStrLn $ act contents)
                   (path: _) -> withFile path ReadMode (\handle -> do
                                                                    contents <- hGetContents handle
                                                                    (print (length $ lines contents)))
                   _ -> putStrLn "Wrong number of argument"
```

EDIT2 : Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in the 4th line of `main`: `opt1` and `opt2` are strings but `argList` returns a list with integer pairs. To fix this you could change `argList` to:

```
argList :: String -> [((String, String), String -> String)] 
argList n = 
    let n1 = read n
    in [(("1", n), extrcta 1 n1)
       ,(("2", n), extrcta 2 n1)
       ,(("3", n), extrcta 3 n1)
       ]
```

Now it compiles (but still does not seem to work as intended; don't understand what your algorithm is supposed to do).

**UPDATE** corresponding to the updated question: That's too complicated. Just drop that `argList` thing and do something simple as:

```
getRow :: Int -> String -> String
getRow n = (!!n) . lines

getField :: Int -> String -> String
getField n = (!!n) . words

getValue :: String -> String -> String -> String
getValue row field src = getField (read field) $ getRow (read row) src

main :: IO () 
main = do
    args <- getArgs         
    case args of                    
        (path: opt1: opt2: _) -> do
            src <- readFile path
            putStrLn $ getValue opt1 opt2 src
```