# cv maillist script

Tags: bash, sh

I've been trying to send many cv at once. But my script doesn't work.
The getrow program works well -> [parse a cv file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7498343/parse-a-cv-file)
Any idea?

EDIT5 :

I was stupid. I forgot that my variable was not i
Here is my revised code (that still doesn't work).
Do you know how to increment $var0?

```
#!/bin/bash

path=~/tests/project_mall
vc=$path/scurricula.pdf
tiv=$path/smotiv.pdf

index=0
LIMIT=$(getrow $1)

while [ "$index" -lt "$LIMIT" ]
do
    (mail1_s $(getrow $1 $index 1) $(getrow $1 $index 2) ; uuencode $vc $vc ; uuencode $tiv $tiv) | mailx -s "candidature spontanèe" $(getrow $1 $index 0)
    echo -n "mail number $index has been sent" ; echo
    sleep 7
    let "index+=1"

done

exit 0
```

EDIT6 : solved, i deleted the output because it contained my mail.
The script above has been edited and works. See ya.

Comment: What error you get? run it with bash -x yourscript and paste the output back

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Will be doing that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the answer is simple. To increment the while loop, you use let `index+=1` with index the variable.

Answer (score 0):

To me this looks like a problem `$var0++`, try `var0 = $var0 + 1` to update the value.

Comment: Yup the error is there. But the replacement doesn't work. The value of $var0 isn't going up.

Comment: post the output after making this change please. Also, modify the variable name so that it doesn't has any number value, rename var0 to index or i to see if it solves the issue.

Comment: my mistake in the answer, try var0 = $var0 + 1 instead of $var0 = $var0 + 1. I have edited my answer as well.

Comment: Doesn't change. The output is basically the same. It gives me an infinite loop. Thanks for the help.